# Language options?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Does anyone know if Deus Ex Human Revolution, (North American edition), will come with Spanish audio/subtitles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started up the game and it has language support for spanish. But while all text displayed was in spanish, the voices and dialogue were all still in english.

Additionnaly, I bought the steam version and live in Canada.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Deus Ex: Human Revolution is available in Spanish, fully translated (including text and audio).

It is a Steamworks game, which in most cases means the "version" you have is not important — Steam allows you to change to any supported language at any time by right-clicking on the game, then choosing *Properties → Language*.

If you are ever in doubt about a Steamworks title in the future, you can simply check [its store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/28050/):

> **Languages:** English, French, German, Italian, Polish, Russian, Spanish

If only some languages have audio support, they will be marked with an asterisk*****. If this is not the case, you can assume all languages listed have full audio support.

Comment: be careful. Steamworks compatible does not mean the game has to support any particular language.

Comment: @Bora Yeah, that's why I said "any *supported* language". DX:HR retail only has a couple of languages available, depending on where you buy it, so the NA retail may not necessarily have Spanish on-disk (but I don't know if that's the case). Once it's installed, Steam offers any localized version that's been made as a download, though.